# How to use Python to automate the movement of data between two Excel workbooks with specific parameters

Tags: python, excel

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
I am working on a personal project to learn python scripting for excel, and I want to learn how to move data from one workbook to another.

In this example, I am emulating a company employee ledger that has name, position, address, and more (The organizations is by row so every employee takes up one row). But the project is to have a selected number of people be transferred to a new ledger (another excel file). So I have a list of emails in a .txt file (it could even be another excel file but I thought .txt would be easier), and I would want the script to run through the .txt file, get the emails, and look for any rows that have a matching email address(all emails are in cell 'B'). And if any are found, then copy that entire row to the new excel file.

I tried a lot of ways to make this work, but I could not figure it out. I am really new to python so I am not even sure if this is possible. Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially two packages that will allow manipulation of Excel files. For reading in data and performing analysis the standard package for use is **pandas**. You can save the files as .xlsx however you are only really working with base table data and not the file itself (IE, you are extracing data FROM the file, not working WITH the file)

However what you need is really to perform manipulation on Excel files directly which is better done with **openpyxl**

You can also read files (such as your text file) using **with open** function that is native to Python and is not a third party import like pandas or openpyxl.

Part of learning to program includes learning how to use documentation.

As such, here is the documentation you require with sufficient examples to learn openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

And you can learn about pandas here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

And you can learn about python with open here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Hope this helps.

EDIT: It's possible I or another person can give you a specific example using your data / code etc, but you would have to provide it fully. Since you're learning, I suggest using the documentation or youtube.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the answer. I really apricate that you included the documentation that I can read because like you said it allows me to learn and that is my only objective at this time.

Comment: You're very welcome @Kevin1772 since you're happy with the answer please select it as the answer & upvote it so others can see. Thanks!